# Passing data always comes back 0

Tags: android, android-intent

I have fixed the problem that I originally create this question for, but now I have a new problem. The activity gets created and it goes to my other screen when I select the button, but now the value that is suppose to get passed to the second activity always comes back as 0.
I am assuming this is the line that is causing it? How, would I fix that?
int goal = intent.getIntExtra("calorieGoal", 0);
My Main Activity.java

```
package net.androidbootcamp.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String selection;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//gets data from the user input
final EditText weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bodyWeight);
final EditText age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yearsOld);
final EditText height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inchHeight);
//gets the spinner selection
final Spinner activityLevel = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.activityLevel);


//initate the button, and set code for when the button is clicked
Button lose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loseButton);
lose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
String userWeight = weight.getText().toString();
String userheight = height.getText().toString();
String userAge = age.getText().toString();

int uWeight = Integer.parseInt(userWeight);
int uHeight = Integer.parseInt(userheight);
int uAge = Integer.parseInt(userAge);
double calorieGoal;
selection = activityLevel.getSelectedItem().toString();
if(selection == "sedentary"){
double bmr = 66.47 + (6.24 * uWeight) + (12.7 * uHeight) - (6.75 * uAge);
calorieGoal = bmr * 1.2;

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gain_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("calorieGoal", calorieGoal);
startActivity(intent);
}

}
});
}
}
```

second activity that I am trying to send the data to

```
package net.androidbootcamp.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Gain_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_gain_);

Intent intent = getIntent();
int goal = intent.getIntExtra("calorieGoal", 0);

TextView texview = findViewById(R.id.calorieGoal);
texview.setText(goal);
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calorieGoal` is of type `double`, not `int`. You will not be able to get it via `getIntExtra`.

Try `getDoubleExtra`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the string error, and bundle error but I did not realize I was trying to use two different types